# .net mvc some users missing cookies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, authorization, missing-cookies

I am using custom forms authentication for an asp.net MVC application, and am having problems with *some* users seemingly not having cookies. The custom forms authentication method we are using is similar to this - [custom forms authentication](http://addisagile.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/custom-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-4/). Essentially, we create a custom Principal and Identity, serialize it, and store it in the UserData property of the FormsAuthenticationTicket :

**Login**

```
MyCustomPrincipal principal = new MyCustomPrincipal(user);
DateTime expiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);

FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1,
                u.Username,
                DateTime.Now,
                expiration,
                true,
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(principal));

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
cookie.Expires = expiration;

Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

We then grab the auth cookie in the Application_AuthenticateRequest event of global.asax.

**global.asax - Application_AuthenticateRequest**

```
// Get the authentication cookie
string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

// If the cookie can't be found, don't issue the ticket
if (authCookie == null) return;

// Get the authentication ticket and rebuild the principal
// & identity
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket =
          FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

MyCustomPrincipal userPrincipal = new MyCustomPrincipal(authTicket.UserData);
DateTime expiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);

FormsAuthenticationTicket newAuthTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
              1,
              ((MyCustomIdentity)userPrincipal.Identity).Username,
              DateTime.Now,
              expiration,
              true,
              JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userPrincipal));



authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newAuthTicket);
authCookie.Expires = expiration;

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(authCookie);

Context.User = userPrincipal;
```

**web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="29" name="MYFORMSAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

This works fine for the large majority of users, however, there are some users who appear to be getting no authorization cookie set. I did a few tests to add more information to my Elmah error logs to see if I could find out more about the problem.

First, I tried setting some test cookies before and after the setting of the authcookie in the Login method. These cookies did **not** appear in the Elmah logs, so it appears adding cookies of any kind in this method is not working. *However*, there are other cookies in the logs, including the ASP.NET_SessionId, a google analytics cookie, and sometimes there are even other cookies I have set at other locations in the application (probably from a previous session)

Second, I tried adding some info to the session from the login action, and including it in the error log if the authcookie was not found on the next action. I included the length of the cookie (the name's length + the encrypted value's length) as well as the time of the attempted login. Both of these are added only if the user's credentials are valid, and the application attempts to add the auth cookie. I **do** see these values in the error logs being produced. The length is always greater than 0, and I haven't seen any bigger that about 2300, so I don't think size is an issue. And the attempted login is identical to the time that the error occurs - so the session variables should have been set immediately before the error occurred (cookies went missing).

A few more notes -

- There doesn't appear to be any browser in particular that seems to be causing the error more (though it is possible it occurs more on mobile browsers)
- Again, the site seems to work for the large majority of users, and of course we cannot reproduce the issue
- Since I am not seeing the test cookies, I am guessing that for some reason *no* cookies are being set from the login method at that time (though I can see other cookies set elswhere that would imply previous successful logins)
- The http referer in the elmah logs is usually set to the login page, which implies that users are probably not hitting the offending page without logging in (at least some of the time) - the state of the session variables seems to support that assumption
- I'm often seeing multiple of these errors in a row (separated by a minute or so) - implying that the issue isn't resolved with repeated login attempts (not sure why it would be)
- It appears users who have this issue continue to have the issue. In other words, it doesn't appear to be "luck of the draw" - but something either with the user's account (which the cookie length session variable implies it is serializing correctly), or the client browser.
- I've heard of at least one user who was able to log in on a mobile device, but not their desktop
- In total the site probably uses 10 or so cookies (including all of the various test cookies that have been added) - before adding the test cookies it used about 4 including the auth cookie. Also, when the bug occurs, there appear to usually only be 2 or 3 cookies in the request, so I don't think number of cookies is an issue.

At this point I'm willing to try almost anything. I tried setting up using the custom identity stored in the session as a backup, but couldn't get that working, so even if anyone has ideas about how to implement that (if possible) it would be appreciated (if this is off topic then I can remove it).

Sorry for the walls of text, but I just wanted to point out all of the potential issues we have investigated and most likely ruled out.

**EDIT**

It appears there may be another potentially related issue. I'm seeing error logs which lead me to believe that the "IsAuthenticated" attribute of some Identities is being set to false when it should not be. We do initialize this to false, and set it to true after the user answers a security question. When we set it to true, it should update the principle and the authentication ticket / cookie. I'm not sure if this is happening because of some issue with how I am deserializing the custom principal or not.

Answer (score 0):

is server side caching enabled?
is I remember exactly I had similar problem and the cause was the server side caching (misconfigured)  and the server side code was not executed but the client reaches the page.
in addition in my side there was a bug (iis bug on caching enabled on dynamic page) that in some situations the session cookie is sent to more than 1 client and this causes unexpected result.

this can explain your non logging behavior and the cookie not present on client.

Regards

Comment: I don't think we use any server side caching, at least not with regards to user sessions or cookies. I'm not as familiar with IIS, so I'm not sure what kinds of things are done automatically. I would think that the problems you describe would likely cause issues with users randomly, as opposed to the same users somewhat regularly (as some of the error logs suggest) We will certainly look into these possibilities though.

Answer (score 0):

So I've sort of given up and decided to use the Session to store my principal, and check it when I don't see the authentication cookie. I can do this somewhat easily by creating a custom Authorize attribute, and checking the session there. I haven't pushed this to production yet, so I'm not 100% sure this will work around the issue, but preliminary testing would suggest it will suffice.

**CustomAuthorizeAttribute**

```
public class MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Get the authentication cookie
        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

        // If the cookie can be found, use the base authentication
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            // The cookie is not found, check the session for the principal

            var p = HttpContext.Current.Session[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

            if (p != null)
            {
                // there is a principal object in the session
                MyCustomPrincipal principal = (MyCustomPrincipal)p;

                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;                   

                // we've loaded the principal, now just do the base authorization
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            }
            else
            {
                // there is no principal object in the cookie or the session, the user is not authenticated
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }

        }
    }     
}
```

Once we've set the current principal appropriately using the custom authorize attribute, we can then just use the base authorization, so we don't have to worry about implementing that functionality ourselves. The base authorization should check the current principal and authorize based off of that.

I'm not going to mark this as an answer, because it doesn't really solve the underlying issue, but I thought I'd provide it as a potential workaround in case someone else stumbled along a similar issue.